# How to open a new tab after the user click on a button

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new in development of Google Chrome extensions.

In my extension, I want to open a new tab after the user click on a button. How I do?

Comment: Please read through the Site [tour], and the [Asking section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) of the Help to get a better idea of what is appropriate for Stack Overflow. On-topic, work through [Getting Started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) and [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create

This took me a single Google search, a single click on one link, and a single Ctrl-F command.  It might be a good idea to look for the answers yourself before posting your questions here.

Comment: I don't understand **how to use**... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chrome.tabs.create()` for that.

Source: [Google Chrome Extensions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create)

You can use it like this:

```
<script>
    // Uses the Chrome API to create a tab.
    function maketab() {
        chrome.tabs.create();
    }
</script>

<button onclick="maketab()">Click me to make a tab!</button>
```

Comment: @RafaelFonseca I added a small tutorial, but you should consider learning JavaScript before learning this since it can be overwhelming.

Comment: Ok. And I have to put this code line on manifest?
`
"permissions": {
     "tabs"

},`

Comment: OP is going to need alot more than this if he finds this confusing.  My recommendation would be for him to work through the extension examples Google provides.